# Geocoder.geocodePosition undefined function error

Tags: react-native, google-geocoder

I'm using 'react-native-geocoder' library, where I have used this piece of code in my app:

```
//reverse - geocoding
 var NY = {
      lat: 40.7809261,
      lng: -73.9637594
    };

Geocoder.geocodePosition(NY).then(res => {
    // res is an Array of geocoding object (see below)
    //location details goes here
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

But getting the error:

> geocodePostion is undefined function

I'm using `"react-native": "0.31.0", "react-native-geocoder": "^0.4.5"` and have followed the configuration steps mentioned in the library.

Comment: why not use '`Geolocation` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html for get location.

Comment: In your error message an i in geocodePosition is missing, however in your code it is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it fixed by this code.I was trying to get the place mark of latitude and longitude

```
  var myAddress = ''

           var NY = {
                  lat: this.state.position.coords.latitude,
                  lng: this.state.position.coords.longitude
                    };

 Geocoder.fallbackToGoogle(MY_KEY);//MY_KEY -- enabled the key googleMapAPI portal.
// use the lib as usual
let ret = Geocoder.geocodePosition(NY).then((res)=>
{
  console.log(res)
  myAddress = res["0"].formattedAddress
  console.log(myAddress);
  this.setState({
          MyAddress: myAddress
        });
})
 console.log(this.state.MyAddress);
```

I'm using "react-native": "0.31.0", "react-native-geocoder": "^0.4.5" and have followed the configuration steps mentioned in the library.